# Wink at / Tipp the wink - usage

Tags: phrases, expressions, idioms

to convey the meaning of "Promised with a wink" what would be a better choice:

> Dan felt like she winked at him that they'd meet in person one day.

This sounds US Eng.

OR

> Dan felt like she tipped him the wink that they'd meet in person one day.

This sounds British Eng.

Tnx,
Tommy.

Comment: Neither sentence is grammatical. *Felt like she . . . that they'd* needs to be rephrased. In particular, *when* should most likely be used somewhere.

Comment: Curious, how you could rephrase it to sound more grammatical.

Comment: (1) *Dan, as she (winked at him / tipped him the wink), felt like they'd meet in person one day.* (2) *When she (winked at him / tipped him the wink), Dan felt like they'd meet in person one day.* (3) *Dan felt like (her winking at him / her tipping him the wink) was a promise that they'd meet in person one day.*

Comment: Thanks! wonder what do you think about:
"How he felt, WHEN she winked at him that they'd meet in person one day.

Comment: That's also ungrammatical.

Comment: @Jason There’s nothing ungrammatical about the sentence as it is. There’s a logical mismatch, but that is just due to the lack of context. Given the context described in Tommy’s comment below, it makes sense that Dan may interpret a wink from the actress on the screen to indicate a future meeting between the two. As Michael’s answer says, “she winked that…” is not idiomatic, but it is understandable, and there’s nothing ungrammatical about it. But there are better ways to phrase it, e.g., “Dan felt like her wink held the promise of one day meeting in person”.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet If by *grammatical* you mean nothing more than syntactic, then you're right. But barring context that wasn't in the question itself, and again as said in the answer, by normal usage of the word, you can't wink *something* at someone. That's not how the words normally work. It might be understood, but that doesn't address the implied question of a good or better phrasing.

Answer (score 1):

To "tip the wink" (one 'P' in 'tip') is a UK idiom meaning to subtly or surreptitiously give someone a piece of secret or private information that might bring an advantage to them. It does not necessarily, or even very often, imply that a physical wink of the eye took place. Your first sentence is not idiomatic. You can't "wink at someone [something]". if you want to say "promised with a wink", then use that exact phrase.

Comment: Thanks Michael. I thought about a similar more idiomatic/poetic usage of "wink at" or "blink at someone" to convey "promised with a wink/ blink. Like in the verb smile / smile at.  "He smiled at her his consent."
But I also know that "wink at" someone means to ignore deliberately... so not sure if the poetic/idiomatic usage can work.

Comment: Of course, if you're being poetic, then all is allowed.

Comment: I am always poetic to a degree..
So, say, if Pluto the dog winks at Dan that he's gonna meet Dan in person (after the movie comes to an end)... will the reader get that Pluto promised Dan with a wink that they'd meet? Or Pluto winking at Dan something will look as if Pluto is ignoring Dan ;)

Comment: I suppose my problem is that while I think a reader might tolerate "she smiled a greeting" or "he frowned a warning", you are placing too big a burden of information transmission on a wink. If you say "she winked that they would meet in person one day" you might as well say "she winked that there were forty-seven crates in the warehouse, and thirteen of these contained obsolete mining machinery; the remainder holding nothing much of any consequence". How does anyone know the meaning of the wink? Also, if he sees her wink, aren't they already meeting in person? Or is she on a TV screen?

Comment: I see your concern. And yes, that's virtual, as a memory. After seeing the theater show, Dan felt like the actress winked at him (from the stage) that they'd meet in person. What do you think, should I cross the bridge or stay with the conventional ;-)

Comment: I once went to see a production of Othello where Iago was played by a well known TV actor. My friend's girlfriend was a fan of his. We sat near the front and she was convinced he was telegraphing romantic messages to her with glances and, yes, winks, so if the reader has access to Dan's thoughts, and we already know he is irrationally hopeful, then maybe. Actors do "work" the audience. It's part of their technique.

Comment: That's what I thought. Maybe I should, after all..  My concern though is the meaning of "wink at" as  ignoring deliberately.

Comment: "Wink at" meaning to deliberately overlook or ignore (usually) some forbidden activity, to "turn a blind eye" to it,  is something else altogether. You don't wink at the person, you wink at something they are doing.

Comment: Yeah, you're right, I should not be afraid of the connotation.

Comment: Maybe when the actress on the stage winks at Don, she could use Morse code? A short wink could be a dot, and a long one a dash?

Comment: Yeah, it's something that Don feels certainly inside, should not necessarily be a real message though.

Comment: By the way, in the phrase "Dan felt like she promised him with a wink" the "felt like" part -- does it sound too much of a street talk? Is "Dan felt as if she promised him with a wink" any better?